# Drupal 6: Change redirect of Node Edit form with Ajax Module installed

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-6, module

Is it possible to do this? I am using hook_form_alter to change the redirect of $form_state and #redirect of $form, as well as changing it using the ajax_alter hook the module uses. Even changing it in both these places it somehow ends up set to redirect to the node being edited.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this [AJAX module](http://drupal.org/project/ajax), it has an useful submodule called *Disable Redirection* that comes with the module. Enable it and remember to enable the checkboxes from the settings.